# 2 values are displaying when we try to edit textfield

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

we are using following code for quantity :

```
$selllermpassignproduct=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($products->getId());
//Zend_Debug::dump($selllermpassignproduct,null,true);
$stock_item=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products);

$SellerQty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['sellerqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['sellerqty']:$stock_item->getQty();
$assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
?>

<span id="valueqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php //echo (int) $SellerQty; ?></span>
<input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "stock" class="ama1" value = "<?php echo (int) $SellerQty; ?>" />



<span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<!-- <img onclick="showField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/> -->
</span>  

<p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p>
<br/>


<button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="buttons" onclick="updateField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>',<?php echo $assignqty;?>); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;"  >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

when we click on update button is displaying like this :

[image]

you can see 2 values , i want to remove the value which is present above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this will do the trick for you

`<span id="valueqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php //echo (int) $SellerQty; ?></span>`

Comment: this is already commented :)

Comment: @MineshPatel i said remove it.. because this is adding it from javascript. i know background of this coding.

Comment: but how commented code work ?

Comment: @MineshPatel  i did't know much about js , it was js issue.... so it worked for me.

Comment: bro i tell you this is updating the value from ajax. so ajax script `id="valueqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"` updating this innerhtml with value.

Comment: ok great but only fixing issue is not our aim

Comment: @QaisarSatti okay okay relax

Comment: @MineshPatel ya, it is my fault that i didt asked how it will work.... becuase i have bundle of problems to solve : - )

Comment: @MineshPatel i am relaxed..